# pdf rendered in canvas and then canvas.toDataUrl(jpegimage) results in a much larger pdf than the original

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, jspdf, pdf.js

Using `pdfjs`, I rendered a single page onto a `canvas` to modify and convert it back to PDF using jsPDF as follows:

```
                const newPdf = new jsPDF({
                    orientation: 'p',
                    unit: 'pt',
                    format: 'a4',
                    compress: true
                });

                newPdf.addImage({
                    imageData: jpegUrl,
                    format: 'jpeg',
                    x: 0,
                    y: 0,
                    width: pdfWidth,
                    height: pdfHeight,
                    compression: 'MEDIUM'
                });

                const url = newPdf.output('datauristring');
```

When I render the pdf onto the `canvas` with its original resolution and convert it back to pdf using `jsPDF`, **without having changed anything**, the resulting file, although of the same resolution as the original, is nearly 6 times larger. 231kb --> 1.3mb.
*Rendering the pdf onto the `canvas` in grayscale also doesn't help reduce the size.

I understand that the file size can be reduced by changing the quality of the jpeg. But I'd like to understand why that would be needed at all, since the resulting pdf is of the same type, viewport, and resolution as the original.

The questions are

1. why does converting PDF to JPEG and back to PDF result in a significantly larger file?
2. Is there anything I can do on the client side to prevent this from happening, or to reduce the file to its original without affecting the resolution?

Comment: In regards to your first question, if the original PDF was mostly text and/or some vector images, then it contained drawing commands, which wouldn't require much space. After rendering to canvas you end up with a bitmap that will look the same but may have much bigger size (in bytes)

Answer (score 0):

Too long for comments

Jpeg is an 8x8 pixel block photo approximation of the page area. Thus if that was mainly whitespace it effectively adds extra noise, whereas Graphics like PNG would add nothing. Thus for a PDF without photos PNG can be 1/2 or 1/3 the size and has better compression and often faster decompression.

Even if there are photos on some pages and they are converted from jpg in spot pages to png in all pages there is not much difference.

So a PNG page of 738 x 1021 in its raw state may be say 1000 colours in about 240-250 KB and default compressed to PDF = 166 KB the same Jpg at 249 KB is  over 7000 colours and fuzzy even at 90% quality and with pdf wrapping becomes 250 KB

Neither will compare well with the source graphics.

[image]

We can improve comparative quality by increasing resolution.
The PDF has not changed size but the Jpeg (1.8 MB) is now nearly 24,000 colours and as a PDF is 1.8 MB whilst the Png (1.3 MB) is still only around 1,000 colours and saves as less than 1.0 MB

[image]